# How to fail a helm release based on inputs in values.yaml

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I'm installing up a helm chart using `helm install` command. I have `values.yaml` which takes a few inputs from the user. One of the keys in `values.yaml` is *action*, which can only take three predefined values (let's say *action1*, *action2* and *action3*) as an input. Any other value other than this is invalid.

When a user provides the value to action field in `values.yaml` and trigger the `helm install` command, the first thing I need to check is that if the *action* key has a valid value or not. If the *action* value is invalid, I want the release to be failed with a proper error message.

e.g.: In case the user has given `action: action4`, this is not valid and release should fail as `.Values.action` can only be *action1*, *action2*, or *action3*.

How I can achieve this use case and which file should be best to handle this validation considering the helm structure?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I was able to achieve the use case with below changes.
Added the following code in _helpers.tpl

```
{{- define "actionValidate" -}}
  {{ $action := .Values.actions }}
  {{- if or (eq $action "action1") (eq $action "action2") (eq $action "action3") -}}
    true
  {{- end -}}
{{- end -}}
```

Invoked this function from a .tpl file like this:-

```
{{ include "actionValidate" .  | required "Action value is incorrect. The valid values are 'action1', 'action2', 'action3' " }}
```

Answer (score 3):

With HelmV3 there is now an easier way. Just specify a [schema](https://github.com/helm/community/blob/master/helm-v3/001-charts.md#schematized-values-files) that includes your values.

For example:

```
 title: Values
    type: object
    properties:
        action:
            description: Some action
            type: string
            pattern: "^(action1|action2|action3)$"
```

Comment: I guess, this solution is more suitable for a complex chart, but if you want to implement a simple validation on few input values, "required" statement is easier.

Answer (score 0):

Not enough rep to comment. However, in response to @Saurabh, you now must YAML comment out the function invocation. Otherwise, Go Template will encounter an invalid return type runtime error from that random `true` value existing in the middle of the invocation file.

Example

```
# validation.yaml
---
#{{ include "actionValidate" .  | required "Action value is incorrect. The valid values are 'action1', 'action2', 'action3' " }}
```