# Can Helm conditionally install main chart based on parameter in values.yaml

Tags: kubernetes-helm

I am not clear if `dependencies` in Helm3 is just for subcharts.

I have 
`license: false` in values.yaml
And I need to install my chart only if `license` is set to `true`.

I went through 
https://helm.sh/docs/topics/charts/#tags-and-condition-fields-in-dependencies

but I couldnt get a way to block the main chart installation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer helped me.
[How to fail a helm release based on inputs in values.yaml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55478581/how-to-fail-a-helm-release-based-on-inputs-in-values-yaml)
I just have to add this condition at one template file and the helm chart wouldn't be rendered.

Problem with `{{- if .Values.license -}}` condition is, helm release would still be provisioned with K8 resources being empty.Also it should be added in all template files.

Answer (score 1):

That's correct, `dependencies` is being used for sub-charts of your main chart. In case you need to deploy your main chart in certain conditions I would suggest following the same steps of the default chart template. For example, you will find a file called `serviceaccount.yaml` which have the following condition:

```
{{- if .Values.serviceAccount.create -}}
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
...
{{- end -}}
```

This means the whole block will not be evaluated unless it met the condition specified. In your case, you need to set a condition in all the chart's templates regardless the `kind`

```
{{- if .Values.license -}}
...
{{- end -}}
```